# Setting CDI in external library

Tags: java, maven, cdi

I'm writing my own little MVC framework and I'm trying to integrate CDI.
The concept is similar to Spring MVC, there is ServletDispatcher and @Controller annotation.

Classes mapped with @Controller should be managed beans.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@IndexAnnotated
@RequestScoped
public @interface Controller {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Then, I want to retrieve Controller class in my library from app context like this

```
Object controller = CDI.current().select(controllerClass).get();
```

But I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI
```

I added dependency in pom.xml in my library

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It's also present in my project that use this library. Already tried to changing scope to provided, but got no luck.

bean.xml is present both in my library and project at main/webapp/WEB-INF/bean.xml

What am I missing? Is it even possible to have library that retrives beans from context of app that use this library?

My application server is TomEE

Comment: Servlets can inject CDI beans. So if you have a dispatcher servlet, simply inject `BeanManager` and use that to get hold of a contextual instance of your controller class. This should work with CDI 1.0 APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TomEE supports Java EE 6/CDI 1.0.

`javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI` was introduced in Java EE 7/CDI 1.1.

You can't simply upgrade the spec APIs when the container is based on an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for a tip that TomEE supports only Java EE6. Solution

```
public class CdiUtils {
    private static BeanManager beanManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) throws NamingException {
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) getBeanManager().getBeans(beanClass).iterator().next();
        CreationalContext<T> ctx = getBeanManager().createCreationalContext(bean);
        return (T) getBeanManager().getReference(bean, beanClass, ctx);
    }

    private static BeanManager getBeanManager() throws NamingException {
        if (beanManager == null) {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            beanManager = (BeanManager) context.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        }
        return beanManager;
    }
}
```